# How do I install VMware-Workstation-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle

Tags: vmware

What is `sudo sh`? Am I supposes to type it in a notepad? Why does it not just have a .exe file where you just click it and it works? Why must Linux be so hard? Whats wrong with having a .exe file to install software? All I want to do is install VMware workstation 10.0, but Linux makes it impossible! Does anyone know a Linux distribution where if you want to install software all you have to do is double click it like in Windows, or is Linux just for intelligent people?  If someone can answer my questions that would be great. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You are asking a lot of questions at the same time. I can understand that learning a new operating system can be tough, but if you want to get good answers it would be really helpful if you would [learn how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/372627/edit) your question and ask what you really wan't to know. Also explain what you have tried and what wasn't working as expected.

Comment: Also, this is not Windows. If you are looking for `.exe` files you may not doing the right way. You may instead open the Software Center instead and install VMware-workstation instead of downloading files.

Comment: I'm just finding it so hard all I want to do is install software like in windows but Linux makes it so hard.  I never fort installing software would be imposable :( I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS I don't like the new one so I'm using this version witch means software like Utorent Vmware and so forth are  not in the Awesome Ubuntu software centre :( so I have to  download software like I would in windows and then install the software but that's where I'm stuck. Software does not install when you click it like windows does and I just cannot get me head around that.

Comment: My 2cents on this: the main problem is that the OP is trying to do a thing "the complex way" --- not an usability problem. Simply go to the Software Center and install the corresponding package. It is as if a new windows user were trying to install a program by moving the DLL and executable in the appropiate directory and then registering them via registry editing...

Comment: And on the other end, the "accusative" tone is not appropriate here. Most people (all?) here is trying to help out of their spare time, to give back something to a great free OS. If you think you have been fooled, ask your money back ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately, Software Center doesn't have VMware Workstation. I checked this in 10.04.4 and 13.04. That's likely why the OP downloaded it from VMware's web site instead.

Comment: I am voting to close this as primarily opinion based because instead of asking a question on Ubuntu, the OP is more going on a rant, or tangent about how they dislike the installation process on Ubuntu. If the OP sees this and would like to [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/372627/edit) their question to meet the rules in the AskUbuntu help center, I will consider closing the vote.

Answer (score 3):

Most of the answers here assume you are comfortable with the terminal, however for ease of use there is a better way to run `Executable` code using just the graphical interface. Here's how you do it:

1. First go to where the file has been downloaded.
2. Right-click on the file and select "Properties"
3. Click on the `Permissions` tab.

   [image: Preview of the permissions tab]
4. At the bottom you will see `Allow executing file as program`, make sure to tick this box (see picture below).

   [image: Marking a file as executable]
5. You can now click on `Close` and Double-Click on the file to run it.

The reason this isn't the default behaviour is for security reasons, to prevent people from running an application that could be untrustworthy. This technique will work on files that end with `.run`, `.bundle`, `.sh` and any file that appears to be a binary/installer.

Ubuntu's version of `.exe` is called `.deb` or "Debian Package Files". This will install similar to what you would expect in Windows, however not everyone (companies) packages installers in this way (as you have noticed). Most will however provide you with an option to download a `.deb` file though.

**Disclaimer: Always make sure you trust where you got the files from first before installing.**

As a side note, you will notice that on the properties dialogue box in Windows also provides a tick box to mark an Executable as safe to run in newer versions of Windows. This option shows up on files that the OS has determined to be downloaded from the internet or from an unknown source.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps to install. First, [download](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?productId=322&downloadGroup=WKST-1001-LX) the correct architecture for your system, then just open terminal, by pressing and holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard. When the terminal window opens, execute the following:

```
sudo chmod 755 VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
```

And that will start the installation.

Comment: kabe@kabe-desktop:~$ chmod 755 VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle
chmod: cannot access `VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle': No such file or directory
kabe@kabe-desktop:~$

Comment: Did you download the right file?  Add `sudo` to the beginning of that first command.  Just edited the answer.  Make sure that you're in the right folder.

Comment: Instead of the cryptic `755`, you can do `chmod +x`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your directory to wherever you unpacked the VMware Workstation. After you have completed that, you need to follow the instructions that Mitch has put on this thread.

Comment: Oh so the .bundle is like .Rar ??  Where you extract the compressed folder and then inside that folder there is something of the equivalent to a .EXE ??  What software do I need to decompress the folder??

Comment: The bundle contains shell script at the beginning to decompress and install itself. Just run it as a shell script in either of 2 ways: using the sh command or turning it into an executable with chmod.

Comment: kabe@kabe-desktop:~$ sh '/home/kabe/Desktop/VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle' 
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module": libcanberra-gtk-module.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  root access is required for the operations you have chosen.

Comment: It did successfully extract the installer. But when it tried to run it, it said "root access is required for the operations you have chosen" Are you running it as root, either by using su or sudo?

Comment: I don't know? I'm the only user as I installed this operating system on My computer that no one uses.  How do i run it as root? do I just type in sudo?

Comment: I get this.kabe@kabe-desktop:~$ sudo
usage: sudo -h | -K | -k | -L | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-p prompt]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U username] [-u
            username|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u
            username|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u
            username|#uid] file ...
kabe@kabe-desktop:~$

Comment: OK. You're almost there. Type `cd /home/kabe/Desktop/; sudo sh VMware-Workstation-Full-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle` . sudo will ask you for your login password - just like Windows asks you to type in the password of an administrator sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

If you see this error

```
root access is required for the operations you have chosen.
```

Then you need to open a terminal and type in:

**`sudo sh VMware-Workstation-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle`**

You need to make sure you have the file `VMware-Workstation-10.0.1-1379776.i386.bundle` in your home directory first.

This solved my problem.

Comment: Always read the question carefully, the user has already shown frustration towards the `usability` of Linux - adding another answer which requires technical knowledge does not add value. Please bare that in mind in the future.